# Playstore is testing my app against random inputs and rejecting it

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, publish, flutter-test

I have made an app on flutter and want to publish it to play store, the first screen of my app is a login screen with email text field and submit button ,the AI is constantly testing the input against bizarre inputs like emojis , white spaces etc and on that basis, its rejecting my app.Please help me, i have tried everything.I have added a video sent by them.[video link](https://fleckstech1-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/aryan_fleckstech_com/ETMkiOU79EZNlVWVhK7FnAUBddCUeY2x-_wkRbd-PO7-eA)

I thought of only allowing numbers,letters,speacial characters but sure it would work or not.

This was their reply email :-[ReplyScreen1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q9UCOBeyDUATd4lhfLGLQ-4uDBQmU6Z9/view?usp=share_link), [ReplyScreen2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ku_CLS9GTnCdD-ddCmzjD7iljBxsPzt/view?usp=share_link).

I added the credentials like this :- [CredentialScreen](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ku_CLS9GTnCdD-ddCmzjD7iljBxsPzt/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: You do realize that practically *any* character can be in a legit standard email address?  The shortest regex to validate an RFC822 email address is about 2400 characters, and is given in https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html.  Anything shorter is WRONG, unless you're using a grammar, as package:email_validator properly does.  Use that for Dart/Flutter please.

Comment: I used [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TanofmiRK9Y1v6d9Z353cMBzNOCTZ-1Z/view?usp=share_link](this) this expression to validate it, i will try using the package now and see if it works or not.

Comment: Yeah, that regex is broken.I can already see things that are legal that are rejected by that, and see things that that accepts that aren't legal.  {sigh}